# Get properties form object and sort by inheritance

Tags: c#, sorting, object, dynamic

I need help sorting an dynamic objects properties by inheritance.

I have a method that should create an ExpandoObject. I'm having trouble with duplicates since "obj.GetType().GetProperties()" takes all the properties regarless of the "new" keyword that is used for hiding properties (**note that the baseproperty is inherited from an other project**).

My solution is to sort all the properties after inheritance level and proiritize the property in the highest derived class. Baseclass should be the lowest prio.

**Is this possible? Look at the second codesnippet to see that I mean.**

*optional extrainfo:
The inparameter object "obj" in my method is of my class "UserEditModel" see inheritance below.
"UserEditModel" derives from "UserModel",
"UserModel" derives from "Otherproject.UserModel",
"Otherproject.UserModel" derives from "Otherproject.PageModelBase"*

**My code right now:**

```
public static dynamic ToExpando(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj is ExpandoObject || obj is LenientExpandoObject)
            return obj;

        var result = new ExpandoObject();
        var d = result as IDictionary<string, object>; 
        var instanceProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        //Add all properties except baseclass properties
        var excludeBaseClassProp = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var excludeBaseClassPropItem in excludeBaseClassProp)
        {
            d.Add(excludeBaseClassPropItem.Name, excludeBaseClassPropItem.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
        //Add the rest of the properties and prevent duplicates
        foreach (var item in instanceProps)
        {
            if (d.AsEnumerable().Any(p => p.Key.Contains(item.Name)))
                continue;

            d.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**What I want to do:**

```
public static dynamic hannes(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj is ExpandoObject || obj is LenientExpandoObject)
            return obj;

        var result = new ExpandoObject();
        var d = result as IDictionary<string, object>; //work with the Expando as a Dictionary

        var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var item in props.OrderBy(prop => prop.INHERITANCE_LEVEL)) //<-----WHAT I WANT TO DO!
        {
            d.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)` excludes inherited properties. `type.BaseType` returns "the type from which the current type directly inherits". Recurse or loop and you're all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett)

This is the result:

```
if (obj is ExpandoObject || obj is LenientExpandoObject)
            return obj;

        var result = new ExpandoObject();
        var d = result as IDictionary<string, object>;

        var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        var propertyInfoGroup = props.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(grp => grp).ToList();

        foreach (var propertyInfoItem in propertyInfoGroup)
        {
            var inheritanceLevelDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int level = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyInfoItem.Count(); i++)
            {
                //Set inheritance levels/depth for each duplicated item and save them in a temp list
                var baseClass = propertyInfoItem.ElementAt(i).PropertyType.BaseType;
                while (baseClass != null)
                {
                    level++;
                    baseClass = baseClass.BaseType;
                }
                inheritanceLevelDictionary.Add(i, level);
                level = 0;
            }

            //Sort the list so the first item will be the one with most inheritances
            var sortedByHighestLevel = inheritanceLevelDictionary.OrderByDescending(k => k.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            var topLevelItem = propertyInfoItem.ElementAt(sortedByHighestLevel.Key);
            d.Add(topLevelItem.Name, topLevelItem.GetValue(obj, null));

            inheritanceLevelDictionary.Clear();
        }
        foreach (var item in props)
        {
            //Duplicated items are handled obove so skip them
            if (d.AsEnumerable().Any(p => p.Key.Equals(item.Name)))
                continue;

            d.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
        return result;
```